# Updating elements for Soduku Puzzle

Tags: list, class, inheritance, tkinter, sudoku

I'm a bit lost at this point. If anyone has some spare time to kill please take a look at this and provide suggestions. Been trying for awhile now to figure this out.
Im having trouble updating the number in the tiles after mouse clicks. Posting the entire code below since its mostly interrelated. Tried to narrow the error down but im not 100 percent positive since I just started learning tkinter. I can get the first square to update by changing the 2-D list to a new create_text method of the canvas problem with this is it leaves all of the previous numbers and id have to do this for the entire 9x9 grid (this is the last line before the else statement in handle_clicks)
 There has to be an easier way of updating numbers?

```
 def handle_clicks(self, event):
    DX, DY = 100, 100
    xclick = self.canvas.canvasx(event.x)
    yclick = self.canvas.canvasy(event.y)
    if (xclick > BORDER_WIDTH and xclick < BORDER_WIDTH + DX and
            yclick > BORDER_WIDTH and yclick < BORDER_WIDTH + DX):
        if self.final_list[0][0] < str(9):
            val = self.final_list[0][0]
            val = int(val)
            val += 1
            self.final_list[0][0] = val
            new_val = self.final_list[0][0]
            new_val = str(new_val)
            self.final_list[0][0] = new_val
            self.id_list[0][0] = self.canvas.create_text(xclick,
                                                         yclick,
                                                         fill = 'yellow',
                                                         text = '%s' %
                                                         new_val)
            print(self.id_list)

        else:
            self.seed_value[0][0] -= 1
```

Full code: http://pastebin.com/2FwaMrdd

Answer (score 1):

> There has to be an easier way of updating numbers?

There is, you can call `Canvas.itemconfigure` to configure the text of the text object on the canvas. In your case, this would be:

```
self.canvas.itemconfigure(self.id_list[0][1], text=new_val)
```